# Image processing - one frame is washed out, other isn't. How to 'fix'?

Tags: image, image-processing, image-manipulation, imagemagick, video-processing

I have the following 2 consequative, unaltered frames from a video:

[image]
[image]

For some reason the camera made the 2nd much 'washed out' than the first. I want to make the 2nd look more like the 1st.

In the video I'm trying to process, there are lots of cases like this, where the 'exposure' changes suddenly from one frame to the next. I am able to find this parts of the video by looking at the image histogram for each frame, and when 2 adjacent frames have histograms that are too far apart, it's where this has happened. I can find this sections of different exposure, but I'm stumped with how to fix it.

As a programmer I'm familar with ImageMagick and that's about it. Since I have lots of frames, some automated hand off approach to fix this is by far the best solution. I am also totally unskilled with graphics editing programmes.

I've tried changing the exposure in imagemagick (with `-level 0,50%` etc.), but that doesn't help.

What ImageMagick commands (or other FLOSS image editing tools) will make the 2nd image look more like the 1st?

Comment: It looks to me like the biggest difference between the frames is the color balance, rather than the exposure. The second image is much bluer.

Comment: I agree, definite colour cast

Comment: after playing around with it in the GIMP, you're right, it's the colour balances. I can change this with ImageMagick's -level command If you add that as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some people have pointed out in the comments, the problem is the colour balance. Changing the colour balance makes the 2 images more similar.